# How to load images for classification problem using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loadimage

I am working on image classification problem using Keras framework. This is binary classification problem and I have 2 folders **training set** and **test set** which contains images of both the classes. I don't have separate folder for each class (say cat vs. dog). Keras **ImageDataGenerator** works when we have separate folders for each class (cat folder & dog folder). But I have all the images in single folder **training set** and I am not understanding how to proceed further. Kindly suggest how to load the images.

I also have 2 CSV files - train.csv and test.csv. train.csv contain 2 columns namely image_id and class_name. test.csv contains image_id. Note that image_id is matching with the name of files in the images folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of `ImageDataGenerator` have a method called `flow_from_dataframe`, which does exactly what you want.

Basically it is used by first loading your CSV file in a pandas `DataFrame`, instantiate a `ImageDataGenerator` and then call `flow_from_dataframe` with three important parameters:

- `directory`: Folder where your data lives.
- `x_col`: Column in the `DataFrame` that contains the filenames inside the `directory` that correspond to your training/testing data.
- `y_col`: Column in the `DataFrame` corresponding to the labels that will be output by the generator.

Then you use this generator as any other, by calling `fit_generator`. More information and examples are available [here](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1).

Comment: Much appreciated @Matias. I was able to load the images using `flow_from_dataframe` and tested it successfully. Thanks again !